# How to change AngularJS data outside the scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input

After hours of frustrating searches I feel I need to submit my question here. I apologize in advance if this question is somehow answered before but none of my searches has helped so far. So here's my question:

My JavaScript code is creating an object, which is modified and monitored by AngularJS. On some events (like loading a previous setting of the object), I wish to change the properties of this object from outside the scope. The problem is that the inputs does not change...

Here's an example of how I wish to perform these changes:

---

HTML code:

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
<input type="number" ng-model="data.age">
<h1>{{data.age}}</h1>

<input type="button" value="Change to 20" ng-model="data" onclick="change()">
```

---

JavaScript Code:

```js
var person = {
    age: 16
};

// Create module
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.factory('Data', function() {
    return person;
});

function FirstCtrl($scope, Data) {
    $scope.data = Data;
}

function change() {
    person.age = 20;
}
```

---

When I now press the "Change to 20" button, nothing happens. How can I modify the person's age from the `change` function?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

> ⚠️ **Warning:** This answer is old, does not reflect best practices, and may not be compatible with newer versions of Angular.

MaxPRafferty's answer is correct - using a function in the scope is often the nicer way to do this - but there is another option. You can use the `angular.element(...).scope()` method to access an Angular scope from unrelated JavaScript. Select the top-level scope for the app by targeting the element that has the `ng-app` attribute specified, with something like in your click handler:

```js
function change() {
    var appElement = document.querySelector('[ng-app=myApp]');
    var $scope = angular.element(appElement).scope();
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.data.age = 20;
    });
}
```

Try it out [in this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremy/kj8Rc/).

[Shaun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/509344/shaunhusain) [just pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17656616/3) that Angular will only process any "watches" or "bindings" during a `$digest()` call. If you just modify the properties of the `$scope` directly, the changes may not be reflected immediately and you may gets bugs.

To trigger this you can call `$scope.$apply()` which will check for dirty scopes and update anything bound correctly.  Passing a function that does the work inside `$scope.$apply` will allow Angular to catch any exceptions as well. This behaviour is explained in [the documentation for Scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope).

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you very much, sir.
Whenever I change the properties of my object outside the controller, I'm having to do this. Isn't that a weird?

Comment: @BirgerSkogengPedersen Angular can be very nice and concise when you're using code that's entirely written in the Angular style (which in this case would mean using `ng-click` with a method defined in your scope), but you're right: it can be quite verbose when you need to communicate between other JavaScript and Angular code. I'm afraid I don't have enough experience with Angular to really comment on how to deal with this.

Comment: Ah, beat me to .scope() Jeremy! As for your question, @BirgerSkogengPedersen, yes that is one of the primary complaints against angular - the general angular response being that if you are modifying scopes using outside code, then you are not adhering to MVC, and are making your code less maintainable. I find this comes up most when dealing with other 3rd party libraries mandated by a project, and often the best way to handle them is to enclose the 3rd party functionality either in the global scope, or in the compile and link functions of a custom directive for it.

Comment: @MaxPRafferty thanks for the knowledge. I'll try to avoid solutions like this in the future

Comment: Did not work for me. My ng-controller is in a child element of the element that has ng-app. Here is the fiddle to show what I'm doing: http://jsfiddle.net/jjr5v9Ld/1/

Comment: Using `ng-controller` instead of `ng-app` or using `$scope = $scope.$$childHead;` works for newer versions. (mentioned in other answers and commented for new visitors like me!)

Comment: Please please please update this answer. Apparently AngularJS dev's think breaking changes are OK for a 1.1 > 1.6 release. Combined with your answer this is a mine-field.

Comment: @WouterSchut Added a warning. I haven't used Angular recently enough to know what I should edit the answer to say beyond that.

Answer (score 15):

[Jeremy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17656244/how-to-change-angularjs-data-outside-the-scope/17656616#17656616) is really good, though now Angular has changed, and will no longer work, unless you add this line of code:

```
$scope = $scope.$$childHead;
```

So, the changed function should look like this

```
function change() {
    var appElement = document.querySelector('[ng-app=myApp]');
    var $scope = angular.element(appElement).scope();
    $scope = $scope.$$childHead; // add this and it will work
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.data.age = 20;
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried but my edits got rejected. check this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306785/editing-an-answer-vs-creating-a-new-one

Comment: Why on earth are there breaking changes between a 1.1 and 1.6 release? Already hate AngularJS after the first 30 minutes of use.

Comment: Strange, here Jeremy's answer is not working in 1.6.4 https://jsfiddle.net/kj8Rc/319/ . OK, I found out, it's because `ng-app` and `ng-controller` are in different div.

Comment: not working on 1.7... even having the ng-app and ng-controller in the same div

Comment: I also ommitted the .data. i.e. $scope.$$childHead.age = 20;

Answer (score 5):

http://jsfiddle.net/MaxPRafferty/GS6Qk/

You want set your ng-click attribute to a function in your scope, as follows:

```
var person = {
    age: 16
};

// Create module
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.factory('Data', function() {
    return person;
});

function FirstCtrl($scope, Data) {
    $scope.data = Data;
    $scope.update = function(){
        $scope.data.age = 20;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I still don't understand how the button would change the age of the person. Even if it does, how would I be able to change the persons age outside the controller?

Sorry if my original question was a little unclear

Comment: Why do you need a factory if you can assign a value directly?

Answer (score 5):

Using Jeremy Banks' perfect answer, done in one line, though I'm referencing the controller vs the app:

```
angular.element('[ng-controller=myController]').scope().$apply(function(x){ x.foo = "bar"; });
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use a short $timeout

```
var whatever = 'xyz';
$timeout(function(){
    $scope.yourModel.yourValue = whatever;
}, 0);
```

and you are done.

I tried all those $apply hacks from around the www before and they all didn't work. But this $timeout works always like a charme and in every case.
All you need is a reference of your $scope and $timeout.

Wy and how it works:

```
// Imagine an angular buildin-function
angular.$queue = function(fn){
    $timeout(fn, 0);
}
```

It works basically like a queue. But be aware that it is async.

Comment: Because $timeout is processed within angulars digest routines. And $timeout with zero (0) time works exactly like a queue. Or in other words: with $timeout(fn, 0) you say "Hey angular, do that next please as soon as you have finished your current work."

Answer (score 0):

With $render method is called by the ng-model directive when the value has been modified outside the directive. Get new value by reading the $viewValue property. Look: https://jsfiddle.net/cesar_ade/g5ybs6ne/

```
ctrl.$render=function(){
    setSelected(ctrl.$viewValue || 'Not Sure');
}
```