# Accessing $scope in javascript angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, set

How do I set `angularjs $scope` in a `javascript function`.
For example in following javascript functions I want to set `$scope.dragged`  and `$scope.dropped`

```js
function drag(e){
    e.dataTransfer.setData("text/html", e.target.id);
    console.log(e.target.id);
                $scope.dragged = e.target.className;
   }
   function drop(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#relationmodal').modal('show');
    e.target.className = "AAA";
    var droppedon = e.target.className;
    console.log(droppedon);
                $scope.dropped = e.target.className;
   }
```

Comment: Include this function inside the angularjs controller, so scope will be accessible and scope related functions can be set !!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change AngularJS data outside the scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17656244/how-to-change-angularjs-data-outside-the-scope)

Comment: @AlhuckA I can't because drag() and drop() calls on the ondragend and ondrop, and angularjs don't have directives like ng-ondragend and ng-ondrop

Comment: don't use inline native events, create your own directive and bind the events inside the directive where you have scope access. Use `angular.element.bind(event, handler)` and `element` is exposed in directives

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="angularid" ng-app='MyModule' ng-controller="MyController">
   Hi
</div>
```

Javascript

```
 angular.element(document.getElementById('angularid')).scope().dragged = 'lorem';

 angular.element(document.getElementById('angularid')).scope().dropped = 'ipsum';
```