# Trigger scope functions from JS outside the controller

Tags: jquery, angularjs, colorbox

I've seen other responses to this on SO, but either I didn't understand how those responses worked in my situation or I'm overthinking this; scopes have always been a poor point of mine.

I'm currently using colorbox for modal windows, containing iframes. To use it in angular, I created an attribute directive that takes the URL of an anchor tag and uses it to trigger colorbox. Typically, when a user does whatever action I need in the modal, I've had JS trigger something in the parent window, to avoid reloading. This seems even more important in Angular, and I'm trying to figure out how I can have said colorbox modal communicate with Angular. So far, the best I can think of is to have the modal's JS change the value of an input (or multiple inputs) to define what I want it to do.

Is there any easier/more direct way?

**EDIT**: Thanks to the solution below, I found the answer:

```
var appElement = parent.document.querySelector('[ng-app=gamersplane]');
var $scope = parent.angular.element(appElement).scope();
$scope.$apply(function() {
    // Do your angular stuff in here!
});
```

The key is parent on the element elector AND before angular.element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it s an angular question in my understanding.

I think this question will help 
[How to change AngularJS data outside the scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17656244/how-to-change-angularjs-data-outside-the-scope)

As you can see in the fiddle available there http://jsfiddle.net/jeremy/kj8Rc/

The change function is a global one, i mean not in the angular scope of execution.

```
function change() {
    // here it fetches the mandatory, and unique (?tobeconfirmed) ng-app HTML element.
    var appElement = document.querySelector('[ng-app=myApp]'); 
    // it finds the scope for you, given that previous element, i believe it s root scope in that case as ng-app.
    var $scope = angular.element(appElement).scope();
    // it s kind of scope binding, it will execute this function within angular scope of execution
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        // then finally appply his change within angular scope of execution, doing so effectively apply the changes
        $scope.data.age = 20; 
    });
}
```

Comment: This seems awesome, but didn't work. If I `console.log(angular.element(appElement).scope())`, it returns null, even though `console.log(angular.element(appElement))` returns me the element in question, so apply() obv wouldn't work. Is it because I'm referencing a parent document? Like I mentioned, I'm trying to trigger it from an iframe.

Comment: Hi, can you confirm origin are the same ? (DNS) Do you have jquery loaded ? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element. Can you check result of the query selector ? Is it possible to implement an example with fiddle ? I did not see myself in a quick attempt how to manage the iframe with it.

Comment: I'll see if plunkr supports iframes and give it a try. But yah, both are in the same origin, jQuery and Angular loaded on both. The query elector gives me back an element.

Comment: Here's a plnkr that shows the issue I'm having: http://plnkr.co/edit/MpkpIDNYIztiB5tqOR3M?p=preview

Comment: Got the solution; I'm editing my post to show the modifications to your code that got it working.