# alternative to adding attribute ng-click to body

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hi I am making a chrome extension and am using angular in order for it not to conflict other angular pages I want to set a ng- click on the body element. I added

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    angular.element(body).click(function(){
        $scope.clickToSelect();
    });
```

inside a controller but It slowed down my code too much and would like an alternative to speed up my code I cannot add a ng-click in the body because I want to make a totally different scope for the controller as not to conflict other directives on the body element.wa

Comment: I would like something that ran outside of the controller as this one is inside but it would need to effect the scope and I'm not sure you can do this outside of a controller also there must be a better way of writing this

Comment: if you want to change the scope from oustside the controller you can follow this procedure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17656244/how-to-change-angularjs-data-outside-the-scope

Comment: @FrancescoLorenzetti84 thanks I used `var body = document.querySelector('body'); angular.element(body).click(function(){
     var appElement = document.querySelector('[ng-controller=mainController]');
    var $scope = angular.element(appElement).scope();
    $scope.$apply(function() {
  $scope.clickToSelect();
  });
    });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to francesco I used

```
    var body = document.querySelector('body');
 angular.element(body).click(function(){ 
    var appElement = document.querySelector('[ng-controller=mainController]');
    var $scope = angular.element(appElement).scope(); $scope.$apply(function() { 
    $scope.clickToSelect(); 
    }); 
});
```