# How to fire an input or change event to trigger AngularJS from external Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I am doing a school project, working on a website that uses forms to send user data to Mailchimp. The site uses Angularjs to control its inputs (I have no access to this code, nor any knowledge about Angularjs).

### What I am trying to accomplish

I want my script to insert whatever text is saved in the *'personalitet'* span into the input by name *'form[5606]'* and accept it as as filled out, without any interaction from the user.

But Angularjs is refusing to see the input at filled out without the user interacting with the field, what can I do?

How do I trigger the input or change event without having access to the Angularjs script or the HTML markup with external JavaScript?

**My Script**

```
var personalitet = document.getElementById("personalitet").innerHTML;
document.getElementsByName("form[5606]")[0].value = personalitet;
```

**The site can be accessed here:** [site](https://campaign.leadfamly.com/game/view/campaign/1448/token:94fc66111e4ebb36534e02d2204fc24d)

I have tried using, without luck:

```
input.trigger('input');
input.trigger('change');
```

Comment: you might need to create the scenario in jsfiddle or plunker. It seems you are trying to bind data to the view but need more information. Note that angularjs is javascript framework and you can always write custom javascript in angularjs apps.

Comment: how do you not have access to angular if you are writing a client side script?

Comment: It is a custom CMS type software the company is using, where I cannot access the scripts, but insert my own.

Comment: what you are trying to do won't work.  You can't update the DOM from outside angular and expect angular to know about it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have however researched this and other questions (and their answers) would suggest that it is possible, like the first answer in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17656244/how-to-change-angularjs-data-outside-the-scope

Comment: yes, but in that answer, the script writer had access to Angular to be able to make use of `$scope`.

Comment: Ah, I thought knowing the top-level scope identifier (in this case ng-app="booztit") was enough? Since it is clearly visible in the page, I was hoping it could be used.

Comment: so then did you get some error or problem when you tried that answer?

Comment: Ah, well, thing is, I am not knowledgeable enough when it comes to javascript to use that answer to solve my problem, if it even would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally managed to make it work and all that was needed was a **.change** to tell Angularjs that the input value had changed. As such, the final scrip was:

```
var personalitet = document.getElementById("personalitet").innerHTML;
document.getElementsByName("form[5607]")[0].value = personalitet;
$( "input[name='form[5607]']" ).change();
```