# Set value in sibling scope without altering directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm using a 3rd party UI framework that's built using Angular. The framework code is all minified and for the sake of simplicity, assume I can't edit the framework code.

[image: Scope Hierarchy]

If the scopes look like the above picture, is there any way at all that I can get write access to a property in scope 6 from scope 43?

Scope 43 is created by my code, 6 is created by the 3rd party library.

Comment: it is not clear which of those scopes are in the 3rd party library and which in your code. We will need a bit of clarification. If all of that is in your 3rd party library, they should have given you some way to change the scope: maybe the property you want to change is two-way binded and you can update it in an outer controller or upper directive (the one that consumes that code). We need more details

Comment: @Gonzalo.- edited

Comment: Without knowing what your third party library is or what options it offers, I can only suggest using `angular.element(someElementInScope6).scope()` (or `.isolateScope` if it's a directive) followed by a `$scope.apply`. See [How to change AngularJS data outside the scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17656244/how-to-change-angularjs-data-outside-the-scope)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments above, I ended up using `angular.element()` to get access to the scope in question, followed by `scope.$apply(function() {myProp=myValue});` to update the value.